# Asset Browser shows only Hair assets in 3.5.0

Tags: asset-browser, asset

In earlier versions, I can import many kinds of assets (e.g. materials, objects, etc.), which are available online.

Is this an expected behavior?

[image]

Comment: It's certainly possible here. Wouldn't be much use if you couldn't add models, materials, etc.! What do you see if you click on the 'All' dropdown at the top left of the window just under the menu icons?

Comment: @JohnEason Yes, it was possible in earlier versions in my environment. Selecting `All` or `Unassigned` changed nothing.

Comment: @Blunder My understanding from the question is that ynn can't add **any** assets to his asset library in Blender 3.5 which is definitely wrong!

Comment: @JohnEason Oh, sorry. You are right. I misunderstood the question. (*I'm going to delete my previous comment*)

Comment: You were probably using an addon like blenderkit or poly haven. In order to add assets to the browser, you need to be in *Current File* instead of *All*

Comment: @Gorgious Hearing that, I think you are right in some sense. Now I come to think maybe I was confusing Cinema 4D with Blender at the time of posting the OP. Thank you :)